# Windows 10 shared drives only being detected by certain machines

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, network-shares, nas

**The problem:**

I'm attempting to create a file server in my room. I have a desktop running Windows 10 with three hard drives: the internal C drive, another internal drive, and a portable USB drive. Unfortunately, while the C drive seems to be reliably detected on client machines, the other drives sometimes don't appear. I have a Windows 10 client laptop and early 2008 MacBook where all the drives reliably appear and another Windows 10 desktop which only the server's C drive appears. Permissions for the shared non-C drives are read, write, execute for everyone on the network. Any ideas to make this network share work reliably?

I have yet to test this on my other computers.

**What I've learned:**

Internet research suggests that drive detection is sometimes unreliable but, after mapping the network drive, access is generally reliable. Is this true? Also, I am a high school student and I will be regularly taking several of my laptops out of the house. I'm given to understand enabling access to public folders sometimes is a workaround to sharing problems so I enabled it.

**Network Settings:**

Network profiles on all machines are set to "private". The server machine has network sharing enabled with automatic setup of network connected devices. The server also has public folder sharing. Password protected sharing is disabled. Permissions for the two auxiliary drives are set "shared" with "everyone" (read, write, execute).

Because my network is secured with a password and has no access to the internet, there is little reason to configure extraneous security precautions, such as restricted user access to drives, which could cause further problems.

Thank you.

Comment: enable SMB1 in Win10 "turn windows features on or off" dialog in desktop control panel

Comment: @magicandre1981 it is already enabled. I'll try disabling and re-enabling...

Comment: @magicandre1981 See my answer for my solution. Thank you for your support :)

Comment: ok, thanks for the update. same name/ip doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unknown to me, the server desktop and the other client desktop had the same computer name. Apparently, a computer name must be a factor in Samba file sharing because, after changing the name of the client, everything works perfectly. Hopefully this information will be helpful to someone.